# How to restrict access to socks5 server only through one hostname?

Tags: domain-name, socks-proxy, subdomain, proxy-server, socks5

I have a **dante-server** (*socks5 proxy*) which points to one of my hostnames (`sub.example.com`). Here's my basic config (my own domain replaced with an example variant):

```
logoutput: /var/log/danted.log

internal: sub.example.com port = 9000
external: sub.example.com

user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

socksmethod: username

client pass {
    from: 0/0 to: sub.example.com
    log: error connect disconnect
}

socks pass {
    from: 0/0 to: sub.example.com
    command: bind connect udpassociate
    log: error # connect disconnect
}

socks pass {
    from: 0/0 to: sub.example.com
    command: bindreply udpreply
    log: error # connect disconnect
}

# Even blocked the main hostname, also tried ".example.com",
# with libwrap compiled and activated (and "hosts.access" too)

socks block {
    from: 0/0 to: example.com
    log: error connect disconnect
}
```

I want to restrict proxy connection only to `sub.example.com`, but I still can connect through other subdomains and `example.com`. Is it possible to restrict to only one hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found workaround but it's a bad practice. Because I'm using DigitalOcean they provide floating IP for each server. I activated it and performed some actions to forward traffic to actual floating IP.

According to this article [How To Use Floating IPs on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-floating-ips-on-digitalocean) you must receive local IP first to perform actions with the floating IP.

1. Type `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/interfaces/public/0/anchor_ipv4/address` on your server and remember received IP address.
2. Edit the `internal` (and `external` if needed) field in your `danted.conf` file to match the received IP.
3. Restart the server.

So now everything works fine except that floating IP's doesn't have IPv6 yet.